# How do I create a button and how do I assign an event to it?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm starting with XNA and I want to know how do I create a button with an event?

Does it looks like C# WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XNA, you wont have access to standard "windows" type controls. you'll have to manually create an object, with dimensions - and test for mouse-clicks inside the area - and behave accordingly.

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=539

Comment: In other words, it's like learning Java Swing in high school (if you can relate).

Comment: If you want a cool library though, I recommend: http://neoforce.codeplex.com/. It may be discontinued and no longer supported, but if you don't want to roll your own buttons (unless this is some sort of learning assignment) you can just use these.

Comment: In addition to neoforce there is my library http://xnagui.codeplex.com/ which is supported :)